# Batch Script Error on Set /P

Tags: batch-file, syntax-error, netsh

I'm trying to get a script to execute something when it detects if an active internet connection is present. This is what I've come up with but I get a syntax error when one one of the if statements isn't run.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('netsh interface show interface ^| find /I "Enabled        Connected"') do @set netsh_output=%%a

SET /P internet_connected="false" 
IF "%netsh_output%"=="Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        WiFi" (
  SET /P internet_connected="true"
)

IF "%netsh_output%"=="Enabled        Disconnected   Dedicated        Ethernet" (
  SET /P internet_connected="true"
)

if "%internet_connected%"=="true"(
  ECHO connected

)
```

It works when I have Wifi but seeing as I don't have ethernet and the second doesn't run it raises a syntax error for no reason. Am I not seeing something I should be?

```
C:\Users\ohheyit'sme\Desktop>IF "Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        WiFi" == "Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        WiFi" (SET /P internet_connected="true" )
true

C:\Users\ohheyit'sme\Desktop>IF "Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        WiFi" == "Enabled        Disconnected   Dedicated        Ethernet" (SET /P internet_connected="true" )
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
C:\Users\ohheyit'sme\Desktop>if "false"=="true"(
```

Comment: Typo: missing space between `"true"` and `(`

Comment: Another typo: `Enabled Disconnected Dedicated Ethernet`. There is one error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Typographical Error

```
if "%internet_connected%"=="true"(
```

should be

```
if "%internet_connected%"=="true" (
```

---

```
IF "%netsh_output%"=="Enabled        Disconnected   Dedicated        Ethernet" (
```

should be

```
IF "%netsh_output%"=="Enabled        Connected   Dedicated        Ethernet" (
```

---

## Mis-using `set /p`

And if you want to set a variable, **not ask for input, do not use `/p` flag**.

```
set Foo=Bar
```

This sets the variable `Foo` with the string of `Bar`.

```
set /p Foo=Bar
```

This sets the variable `Foo` to user's input.

Comment: Thankyou. I also found some of the same bugs you did in my code including 'disconnected' in the second if statement when it should have been 'connected'. Apart from that, it's working now :)